# button in XSL for AJAX usage

Tags: xml, ajax, button, xslt, javascript

I wonder if its is possible to do AJAX when I put a button inside the xsl file;

```
<input type = "button" id="laptop" value = "Add to Cart" onclick="sendCartRequest('Add');" />
```

That's what I do in my xsl file then in my js file I pass the id to the DOM and try to alert it make sure it is passed.
And the alert appear to be empty.

Is it a mistake to put the button in the xsl? or that's something else that cause it's empty? May be my DOMpath?

Please point me a right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one  `<input>`on the page, then you might want to try generating the id field:
`<input type="button">

    <xsl:attribute name="id">laptop_<xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/></xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">sendCartRequest('add',this)</xsl:attribute>

</input>`

in your javascript `sendCartRequest` method, note that I have added a "**this**" parameter. Inside this function you can retrieve which button was clicked by examining the id attribute.

If the id attribute uses a product id or something that is used from the xml, even easier to send the transaction.

comment on my response if you need more details.